# Unable to access SecretsManager from lambda (inside a VPC)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, amazon-vpc, aws-secrets-manager

I've been trying to get a db connection working in my lambda and having the worst time retrieving my password from secrets manager.

When I run the lambda I get

```
User: arn:aws:sts::#####:assumed-role/consent-gen/consent-gen is not authorized to perform: secretsmanager:GetSecretValue because no identity-based policy allows the secretsmanager:GetSecretValue action
```

Policy Simulator tells me I have access rights however, in addition to the console telling me I have rights
[image: policy simulator]
[image: lambda console]

While the lambda is in a VPC, it is in private subnets
[image: lambda vpc info]

And I have a VPC Endpoint for secrets manager set up, in the same vpc/subnets
[image]

with a security group set up to allow inbound traffic from the VPC i'm on
[image]

I'm at a loss at this point, has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: The error regards the role named `consent-gen`. Are you sure this role has permissions for `secretsmanager:GetSecretValue`?

Comment: Yeah, it definitely does and I tested it with Policy Simulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the question author to move it to the answer space)*.

I did absolutely nothing, but the error disappeared. I'm guessing I needed to wait longer for something in the VPC endpoint to be set up internally to AWS but I honestly don't know. Such is the mystery of AWS.

Answer (score 0):

I would check the following:

- Check to make sure your secret does not have a Resource permission attached to it or that the resource permission allows your lambda role to retrieve the secret
- Check to make sure there are no SCPs preventing you from retrieving the secret
- Verify that the role attached to your lambda is what you expect it to be
- Check that the role your lambda is assuming has permissions to the KMS key that is encrypting the secret.  I've seen misleading errors in that past that end up being kms key permissions errors.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, definitely thoughtful and helpful. I'm closing this question because after going to bed and getting up, the error has disappeared. I did absolutely nothing, I literally just hit the test button on the console again to bring up the error and the request went through. I'm guessing there was something being set up with the VPC endpoint in the background that just required time, but I'm honestly not sure. Thanks again for your help